# Use of になる and で in 同姓同名になる事で

Tags: grammar, particle-で

I am trying to figure out the meaning of the following :

> 同姓同名になる事で

It is part of a newspaper article on a Japanese Mayor whose name and surname sounds like "Joe Biden"

The entire sentence is

> 同姓同名になる事で、米紙ワシントンポストやニューズウィーク、英紙ファイナンシャルタイムズなど各国のメディアに取り上げられました。

translated as

> The mayor’s surname was picked up by the media of various countries, including The Washington Post, Newsweek, and the Financial Times.

I read [about Using 〜になる instead of です](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32727/using-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b-instead-of-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99) and about で usage but there are still 2 things I don't understand:

1. Why using ~になる and not です ? The mayor name and surname won't change, it's a static thing. Is it because we are focusing on the fact that the mayor "popularity" is currently growing because of his name? Like "the fact that his name sounds like Joe Biden is known worldwide" is an ongoing thing (a process that changes and develops over time)?
2. Why で? I understand it could mark a method/circumstance (something like "newspapers are writing about him only because of his name") or a length of time inside which something occurs (like "his name sounding like Joe Biden only matters for now because of the recent american election"). Is there another explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your sentence seems to come from this [article](https://newsinslowjapanese.com/2020/12/29/nisj-364-the-joe-biden-of-japan/). Please provide more context next time. The ~になる is used instead of ~です because the mayor's name was in process of changing.

> The mayor name and surname won't change, it's a static thing.

This is true, but the name changing in this context is kanji-based. Yutaka Umeda's kanji name could be read alternatively as "Joe Biden."

2. The で used in the sentence is the て-form of だ, which connects two related clauses. <s>It is not a particle.</s> Your sentence can be reworded into something like this

> 同姓同名になる事**だ**。**そして**、米紙ワシントンポストやニューズウィーク、英紙ファイナンシャルタイムズなど各国のメディアに取り上げられました。

You can think of it as a particle that marks a reason for media coverage.

See @Chocolate's answer for more info.

Comment: Thanks. When you say *the mayor's name was in process of changing* do you mean something like "because of the american election more and more people are **choosing** to use the On-reading of his name ?" i red [about On-reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji#On'yomi_(Sino-Japanese_reading)) but i still don't understand how a native speaker could know the right reading of a name (ex : someone he/she doesn't know)

Comment: @xavier Sorry for being vague about that. When I said his name was in the process of changing, what I actually meant was his name can *become* the same name as Joe Biden if the On-reading of his name changes. The article didn't mention anything about more people preferring to use this On-reading. It only states a fact, which is picked up by the media. It's rare for native speakers to correctly figure out the right reading of the name if it's presented for the first time.

Answer (score 5):

> 日本語の漢字は音読み、訓読みがあり、梅田穣町長の梅田（うめだ）という漢字は『バイデン』と読むことができ、穣（ゆたか）という漢字は、『ジョー』と読むことができます。同姓同名に**なる事で**、米紙ワシントンポストやニューズウィーク、英紙ファイナンシャルタイムズなど各国のメディアに**取り上げられました**。

「～～**ことで**新聞・ニュース・メディア等に**取り上げられる**」 means "**is featured** in the newspaper/news/media **for ~~ing**."

So the で is a particle. Here it indicates the **reason** for being picked up by the media.

The article is saying:

> （梅田穣を音読みすると・梅田穣をバイデンジョーと読むと）同姓同名になることで、（梅田町長が）メディアに取り上げられた。

"(Mr Umeda was) featured in the media for becoming the same name (if his name is read in On-reading/if his name is read as Baiden Jou)."

Similar examples of this usage of で:

> 京都は古い神社仏閣**で**有名です。
> Kyoto is famous **for** its old temples and shrines.
> ボルタは電池を発明した**ことで**知られている。
> Volta is known **for** invent**ing** the electric battery.